# Cursor problem in Ubuntu

Tags: 18.04

I have installed a fresh copy of Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. The problem is that my cursor moves in opposite direction. I have tried some of these commands in terminal:

`sudo apt-get update`  but I get that

> some of the index files failed to download. They have been ignored or
>   old ones used instead

`sudo apt-get upgrade`  and after press y I get

> Unbale to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with
>   --fix-mix sing?

```
 sudo apt-get remove iio-sensor-proxy
```

> Unable to locate package to iio-sensor-proxy

Also tried `sudo apt remove iio-sensor-proxy`
And get the same above error.

Comment: Providing us with the full output of the messages (or at least the part that errors relate to) allow us to provide more helpful advice.  I'd check the sources are valid (if unofficial, do they support bionic?) or if mirror - is the mirror maintained correctly and up-to-date.  We can't see the detail necessary to advice so look at the detailed error messages (or paste for us to help you)